# Bernoulli number analog identity

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory

I am doing work on Bernoulli numbers.  Let $$b(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty{\frac{B_k}{k!}x^k}=\frac{x}{e^x-1}$$
From this, by taking derivatives of both sides we get the identity
$$b(x)^2=(1-x)b(x)=xb'(x)$$

Now I'm working on a different function.  Let
$$a(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty{\frac{A_k}{k!}x^k}=\frac{x^2/2!}{e^x-x-1}$$
Now if I differentiate $a(x)$ i get
$$a'(x)=\frac{2x-x^2}{2(e^x-x-1)}-\frac{x^3}{2(e^x-x-1)^2}$$
$$a'(x)=\frac{x^2}{2(e^x-x-1)}\left[\frac2{x}-1-\frac{x}{e^x-x-1}\right]$$
$$a'(x)=a(x)\frac2{x}\left[1-\frac{x}{2}-a(x)\right]$$
$$\frac{xa'(x)}{2}=\left(1-\frac{x}{2}\right)a(x)-a(x)^2$$
$$a(x)^2=\left(1-\frac{x}{2}\right)a(x)-\frac{x}{2}a'(x)$$
$$2a(x)^2=(2-x)a(x)-xa'(x)$$
THis seems to me to be an accurate and completely analagous identity on $a(x)$.  Can anyone verify my calculations are correct?

Comment: Looks OK to me.