# Finding convolution identites

Tags: sequences-and-series, reference-request, special-functions, convolution

Suppose I have the following definition:
$$\frac{x^2/2!}{e^x-1-x}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}A_k\frac{x^k}{k!}$$

I want to find a convolution identity for these coefficients $A_k$, but I've never studied convolutions before.  Essentially, what I would like to find is a way to write $A_n$ in terms of a finite convolution, where $$A_n=C\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}c_{nk}A_kA_{n-k}$$ or$$f(n)A_n=\sum{A_kA_{n-k}}$$or something along those lines...

I don't even know if it is possible, but what I am looking for is guidance to approach these problems.  What are the best methods for developing convolution identities and what approaches work well?

EDIT:
I was able to find a convolution identity using Cauchy products and an [identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/946418/bernoulli-number-analog-identity) to come up with 
$$\sum_{j=2}^{k-2}\binom{k}{j}A_jA_{k-j}=-k\left(A_k+\frac1{3}A_{k-1}\right)$$
which is kind of bittersweet since (1) I found one (2) it is not an identity in only $A_k$.  Any thoughts on how I can find a similar formula that kills the $A_{k-1}$ term OR that removes the binomial coefficients in the summation and leaves me with $\sum{A_jA_{k-j}}=f(k)A_k$?

EDIT 2:
I feel like my desire is to have a convolution identity of the form
$$A_n=g(n)\sum{A_kA_{n-k}}$$ or something of this form.  My trouble with this lies in the fact that the numbers $A_k$ are defined by an exponential power series which places $k!$ into the denominator of the coefficients of the power series.  can anyone think of a way around this?

Comment: Do you need a convolution identity of the form $\sum_{k=0}^n A_{k}A_{n-k}$, or would one of the form $\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{A_{k}}{k!}\frac{A_{n-k}}{(n-k)!}$ be satisfactory? The latter seems more compatible with your exponential generating function.

Comment: All the research I've done so far points me to what you are suggesting, because of the exponential generating function.  My example in the question was more of a very general view of what i was looking for.

Comment: I would point out though that something like $\sum{A_kA_{n-k}}$ would be fantastic...

Comment: Okay. Then you may want to pose it more generically as finding $A_n = \sum_{k=0}^n C_{nk}A_k A_{k-n}$ to allow weighted convolution identities.

Comment: $A_k$ are the [generalized Bernoulli numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number#Generalized_Bernoulli_numbers), whose [numerators](http://oeis.org/A006569) and [denominators](http://oeis.org/A006568) are found on OEIS.

Comment: Thank you, Lucian.  Yes, I know what they are, I'm just looking for ways to generate convolution identities.  I have some work already buy it's messy and since I'm new to the subject matter I was just looking for strategies to generate these if possible