# 2nd Derivative verification

Tags: calculus, combinatorics

I have a function, $a(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{A_n}{n!}x^n=\frac{x^2/2}{e^x-1-x}$. From my post [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/946418/bernoulli-number-analog-identity) i was able to derive the identity,
$$2a(x)^2=(2-x)a(x)-xa'(x)$$
Now, taking the second derivative:
$$\frac{d}{dx}[2a(x)^2]=\frac{d}{dx}[(2-x)a(x)-xa'(x)]$$
$$4a(x)a'(x)=(2-x)a'(x)-a(x)-xa''(x)-a'(x)$$
$$4a(x)a'(x)=-a(x)+(1-x)a'(x)-xa''(x)$$
Multiplying both sides by $x$,
$$4a(x)[xa'(x)]=-xa(x)+x(1-x)a'(x)-x^2a''(x)$$
By rearranging the original first derivative identity and substituting for $xa'(x)$ on the LHS,
$$4a(x)[(2-x)a(x)-2a(x)^2]=-xa(x)+x(1-x)a'(x)-x^2a''(x)$$
$$2(2-x)\cdot2a(x)^2-8a(x)^3=-xa(x)+x(1-x)a'(x)-x^2a''(x)$$
$$-2(2-x)\cdot2a(x)^2+8a(x)^3=xa(x)-x(1-x)a'(x)+x^2a''(x)$$
Substituting in from the original first derivative identity for $2a(x)^2$,
$$-2(2-x)\cdot[(2-x)a(x)-xa'(x)]+8a(x)^3=xa(x)-x(1-x)a'(x)+x^2a''(x)$$
$$8a(x)^3-2(2-x)^2a(x)+2x(2-x)a'(x)=xa(x)-x(1-x)a'(x)+x^2a''(x)$$
Isolating $8a(x)^3$,
$$8a(x)^3=[x+2(2-x)^2]a(x)-[x(1-x)-2x(2-x)]a'(x)+x^2a''(x)$$
$$8a(x)^3=(2x^2-7x+8)a(x)-(x^2-3x)a'(x)+x^2a''(x)$$

I think this is good.  Can anyone verify it's equality?  I've done the problem about 5 times with 3 different answers (not very different), but I think this is the correct one...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed a negative sign in $2x(2-x)a^|(x)$ while isolating $8a(x)^3$

Comment: I fixed that a couple of minutes ago...can you reverify?

Comment: no you haven't @Eleven-Eleven

Comment: Oh, wait, so it should be $[x(1-x)+2x(2-x)]a'(x)$ then...

Comment: And in the final solution the first derivative coefficient should then be $(5x-3x^2)$?  Thanks for the help...

Comment: is the quadratic coefficient correct then too?

Answer (score 0):

i got for $a'(x)$ the following result
$a'(x)=\frac{2a(x)^2-(2-x)a(x)}{-x}$  (1)
and now $a'(x)(4a(x)-1+x)+a(x)=-xa''(x)$ (2) now we can put (1)  in (2)
now i have
$a''(x)=\frac{8a(x)^3-10a(x)^2+6xa(x)^2+2a(x)-4xa(x)+x^2a(x)}{x^2}$

Comment: Yes, that is the first derivative.  I want the second derivative and I want it in terms of $a(x)^3$  which means I'm looking for 2nd order differential equation.

Comment: I understand what you are doing, but I need $a(x)^3$ in terms of $a(x), a'(x),$ and $a''(x)$.  The fact that you have the $a(x)^2$ term deviates from my goal...